# windows vista cannot install updates

Tags: windows, windows-vista

When I go to windows updates my computer will quickly search for updates and then ask me to reboot to install upates.  It will appear to start installing updates for about 10 seconds and then reboot. I have tried this time and again with the same results.  No error messages are given.

When I open windows updates it says I have never searched or installed updates.  When I look in updates history it will show me all the updates that I have installed.

I have tried many solutions given on you tube without success.  Is there a way to resolve this problem?